# Twisted server TLS hanging on connection

Tags: python, ssl, smtp, twisted

I have a twisted webserver with TLS authentication, and it appears to hang when I connect to it over SMTP.  Here is the block of twisted code to start the server:

(Note: certificateData is our private key and public key concatenated together, that appeared to be the only way to get a self signed certificate to work)

```
customFactory = CustomSMTPFactory(portal)
certificate = PrivateCertificate.loadPEM(certificateData)
contextFactory = certificate.options(certificate)
tlsFactory = TLSMemoryBIOFactory(contextFactory, False, customFactory)

a = service.Application("Custom Server")
internet.TCPServer(5870, tlsFactory).setServiceParent(a)
```

On the client, this line just hangs waiting to read data:

```
smtplib.SMTP('localhost',5870)
```

Any ideas?  How do I setup TLS authentication on a twisted webserver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your server starts TLS from the beginning of the connection.  Try [`smtplib.SMTP_SSL`](http://docs.python.org/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP_SSL) instead, so your client expects this.

Comment: Yep that would work.  I solved me problem another way though- namely, the standard ESMTP protocol handles tls communication provided it is setup properly with private/public keys.  So I do not need to wrap my factory in the TLS factory- it will negotiate the TLS comm once it is connected.  Thanks though.